# How do I change the listview background gradient on fingerpress and finger release

Tags: java, android, listview, user-interface, gradient

How do I change the background gradient to something on tapping and get the original gradient on finger release ...the the list I created using list view adapter does change to a gradient but does not change back to original gradient when I lift up the finger.. xmls below

**main.xml**

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#EDEDED"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
  />
```

**list_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Selector style for listrow -->

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover"
    />

<item
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

   <item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

</selector>
```

**row_list.xml**

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txtListText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textSize="45sp"


    />
```

gradient_bg and gradient_bghover are gradient xml's..

Answer (score 0):

I think, youn can't define state_selected and state_pressed at once...

something working should look like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/_bt_week_selected" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/_bt_week_selected"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/_bt_week_selected"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/_bt_week_normal"/>
</selector>
```

and set the background of the list items (row_list) to the selector... like `android:background="@drawable/selector"`... instead of using `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"`
I don't know if your's is working as well...